# Calculated value for margin to mimic max-margin and min-margin in CSS

Tags: css

I try to set the margin on an object with a margin of 20% with a max margin of 200px. I tried several things such as:

```
margin-left: calc(min(200px, 20%));
```

and

```
 max-margin-left: 200px
```

But both properties are invalid. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: There is no such property `max-margin-left` exists till now

Comment: With CSS I doubt. You have to use JS and calculate the margin each time on window resize.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not set a `max-width` on your element, and set padding to 20%?

Comment: I have a bootstrap grid with col-2 (side-nav) col-8 and col-2, the sidenav has a max width of 200px and is absolute positioned. Therefore I need to add a margin to the col-8 because otherwise this would placed on top of the side nav. I can add a margin in percentages but that means that in the full page (when the size of the side-nav is smaller than col-2 not col-2 but 200px, there is too much space between the side nav and the col-8.

Comment: @Reinier why not just put an empty col between those elements? Like `col-2`, `col-1 (empty)`, `.col-7` and `col-2`.

Comment: The problem is that this will not work when the size of the first column with a max width changes. My solution for this was now to give up on the resizing of the left nav (so fixed width of 200px) and to add a calculated margin left to the right div of margin-left: calc(66.7% + 200px)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if its syntax related but have you tried ?

margin-left: calc(20% - 200px);